# Ошибка в получении контента

Tags: php

Подскажите, как исправить код

```
<?
 $urlp = "http://all-x.ru/?i=32238&c=1";
 $code = @file_get_contents($urlp);
 echo $code;
?>
```

Comment: насколько я могу судить, `php` код рабочий.

а вот JS на запрашиваемой странице меня ставит в тупик.

Comment: это код счётчика, который я должен вствавить между тегами <BODY></BODY>, но когда я его вставляю выдает ошибку: Не удалось проанализировать ваш шаблон, так как он неправильно сформирован. Убедитесь, что все элементы XML правильно закрыты. <br/>Сообщение об ошибке в XML: The processing instruction must begin with the name of the target.

Comment: что за CMS? 

строчку с <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"... в студию